# How do I do Port Forwarding on a ZTE F6600P Router?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I want to host a [dedicated server on Arma 3](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arma_3:_Dedicated_Server) but I don't know how to do that.

I watched many different tutorials and every port forwarding screen was entirely different from my own.

Is IP Filtering the same as [Port Forwarding](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Arma_3:_Dedicated_Server#Port_Forwarding)?

Also, secondary question, does that router model support UPnP? If so, how do I activate that?

Comment: Look in your Router setup for Firewall. Port Forwarding or Opening Ports and set up from there.  I took the above from my Cisco router.

Comment: The first question to even determine if this will be possible is for you to confirm you are not behind a CGNAT.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to
[check if your ISP performs CGNAT](https://www.purevpn.com/blog/how-to-check-whether-or-not-your-isp-performs-cgnat/)
by comparing the  router's WAN IP and the public IP address.

If there is no CGNAT by your ISP, then follow the advice in the article
[Simple Instructions to Help Setup a Port Forward on the ZTE F660 Router](https://portforward.com/zte/f660/).

In a nutshell, the procedure is :

> 1. Setup a **static IP address** on the device or computer you want a port forwarded to.
> 2. Login to your ZTE F660 router.
> 3. Navigate to the port forwarding section.
>
> - Click the **Application** link.
> - Click on **Port Forwarding**.
> - Click on **Advanced**.
>
> 4. Create a **port forward** entry.

Another helpful resource is the article
[ZTE F660 Port Forwarding](https://openmyip.com/ZTE-F660-router-setup).